# save previous mapping in vim

Tags: vim

I remap a key to catch that the key was pressed and call a function where it is decided to invoke an action or to invoke the key as this remapping does not exist. But the problem is that when I remap a key I lose the action mapped to that key.

Hot I can implement this in vimscript?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "this remapping does not exist"; what is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Either way, it sounds like you need [`:normal!`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:normal) and maybe [`:execute`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:execute).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:h :normal` in your function to recreate the original functionality of the key you remapped. For instance...

```
nnoremap l :call MyFun()<cr>

fun! MyFun()
    call inputsave()
    let choice = confirm("Call fun?", "&yes\n&no", 1)
    if choice == 1
        call OtherFun()
    else
        norm! l
    endif
endfun

fun! OtherFun()
    echo "It worked!"
endfun
```